# tmux blocks for certain commands

Tags: tmux

I am trying to understand why this program behaves differently depending on Y:

```
#!/bin/bash

rm -f /tmp/par21d9I.tmx
mkfifo /tmp/par21d9I.tmx; 
tmux new-session  -d  true\ 11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111$Y\;\ perl\ -e\ \'while\(\$t++\<3\)\{\ print\ \$ARGV\[0\],\"\\n\"\ \}\'\ \ \>\>\ /tmp/par21d9I.tmx\&sleep\ .1;

exec perl -e '$/="/";$_=<>;$c=<>;unlink $ARGV; /(\d+)h/ and exit($1);exit$c' /tmp/par21d9I.tmx
```

tmux version 1.8:

```
Y=Y prg
#OK

Y=YY prg
#Blocks

Y=YYYYYYY prg
#Blocks

Y=YYYYYYY prg
#OK
```

tmux version 1.9a:

```
Y=Y prg
#OK

Y=YY prg
#Blocks

Y=YYYY prg
#Blocks

Y=YYYYY prg
#OK
```

Any idea why the program hangs for some values of Y?